# How to update a label with the current date in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3

I have two labels: label1 and label2. In label 1 want the day, and in label 2 I want the month followed by the date.

Example:

> Thursday
>   Jun 30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 let today = Date()
 let weekday = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: today)
 let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: today)
 let date = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: today)

 label1.text = Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols[weekday-1]
 label2.text = "\(Calendar.current.shortMonthSymbols[month-1]) \(date)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get today values like this:

```
let today = Date(timeInterval: 0, since: Date())
let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: today)
let day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: today)
```

Then you could update your label like:

```
label1.text = "\(day)"
label2.text = "\(month)"
```

Comment: I tried this code.. But Xcode says : Cannot use instance member 'today' within property initializer.

Comment: Post you whole code, to see where you are putting it, you should put it on viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear.

Comment: It Works! Thanks!! But.. It shows the month in number not words.. What do i do?

Comment: The 1st line here can simply be `let today = Date()`.